# Extension content script multiple mouse events handling

Tags: javascript, firefox-webextensions

I'm writing a translate extension for firefox just similar like google translate extension. 
I achieve that the listening mauseup and mousedown events to get selection text and popup a div that you can click.

Due to i am new at javacript, i would like some feedback for above code.
 Can i do any improvement?

```
var bubbleDOM = document.createElement('div');
bubbleDOM.setAttribute('class', 'selection_bubble');
document.body.appendChild(bubbleDOM);
var selection = "";
function getSelectionText() {
  var text = "";
  if (window.getSelection) {
    text = window.getSelection().toString();
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control"){
    text = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
  return text;
}
document.addEventListener("mousedown", checkSelectionText);
document.addEventListener("mouseup", checkSelectionText);

function checkSelectionText(event) {
  if (event.target == document.querySelector('.selection_bubble')) {
    return;
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    selection = getSelectionText();
    if (selection) {
      document.querySelector('.selection_bubble').style.top = (event.pageY+3) + "px";
      document.querySelector('.selection_bubble').style.left = (event.pageX+3) + "px";
      document.querySelector('.selection_bubble').style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
      document.querySelector('.selection_bubble').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
  });
}

document.querySelector('.selection_bubble').addEventListener("click", openPopup);

function openPopup(event) {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: 'openModal', selection: selection});
  document.querySelector('.selection_bubble').style.visibility = 'hidden';

  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```